# c# operator overloading usage

Tags: c#, overloading, operator-keyword

```
public static ListOfPeople operator +( ListOfPeople x, Person y)
    {
        ListOfPeople temp = new ListOfPeople(x);
        if(!temp.PeopleList.Contains(y))
        {
            temp.PeopleList.Add(y);
        }
        temp.SaveNeeded = true;
        return temp;
    }
```

So, I've never used the overload functionality of operators, and I'm trying to make sense of how to add objects from my class (Person) to my Collection class (ListOfPeople).

ListOfPeople contains an attribute `List<Person> PeopleList`;

My difficulty is in how to get a pre-existing List inside of this method to add a new Person to. `ListOfPeople temp = new ListOfPeople(x);`

I have an error on this line because I have no constructor that takes a ListOfPeople argument. If I were to make it `ListOfPeople temp = new ListOfPeople();` then Temp would just call my default constructor where I simply create a new, empty list, and that doesn't allow me to add to a pre-existing list either.

I'm just not sure how I get 'temp' to actually reference my pre-existing list.

Comment: You shouldn't use the + operator to add items to a collection. I believe this is even given as an example where operator overloading should **NOT** be used.

Comment: Well, it's adding an object to a List contained within a Collection class. Is that still equally bad?

Comment: Yes, just look at how other .NET lists implement adding items, it's always through an `Add` method.

Comment: I wouldn't use an operator in this way personally - not idiomatic for .NET; but ***if I did*** - I wouldn't do the `Contains` check. If somebody wants to add it multiple times, that is their issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use as follows:

```
public static ListOfPeople operator +( ListOfPeople x, Person y)
{
    ListOfPeople temp = x;
    if(!temp.PeopleList.Contains(y))
    {
        temp.PeopleList.Add(y);
    }
    temp.SaveNeeded = true;
    return temp;
}

public static ListOfPeople operator +( Person y, ListOfPeople x)
{
    ListOfPeople temp = x;
    if(!temp.PeopleList.Contains(y))
    {
        temp.PeopleList.Add(y);
    }
    temp.SaveNeeded = true;
    return temp;
}
```

- 1st allows you to use: `list = list + person`
- 2nd allows you to use: `list = person + list`

You may also want to overload `+=` operator (non-static) so that you can use `list += person`

## EDIT

Though I solved the problem mentioned. But, then, I agree with others on the operands of '+' being immutable.

Below is update to existing code (assuming `ListOfPeople.PeopleList is List<Person>`):

```
public static ListOfPeople operator +( ListOfPeople x, Person y)
{
    ListOfPeople temp = new ListOfPeople();
    temp.PeopleList.addRange(x);
    if(!temp.PeopleList.Contains(y))
    {
        temp.PeopleList.Add(y);
    }
    temp.SaveNeeded = true;
    return temp;
}

public static ListOfPeople operator +( Person y, ListOfPeople x)
{
    ListOfPeople temp = new ListOfPeople();
    temp.PeopleList.addRange(x);
    if(!temp.PeopleList.Contains(y))
    {
        temp.PeopleList.Add(y);
    }
    temp.SaveNeeded = true;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: I thought += was implicit once you'd defined +?

Comment: My bad. Yes. `+=` resolves to `+`. LH operand depends on LHS of +=. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx

Comment: I would really really discourage something like this! It implies something that is not given! With (a+b) I would expect that a will remain untouched and I get a new result. With your code the list will change, no matter if you assign the value or not!

Comment: Agree to what @JustAnotherUseYouMayKnow wrote :)